# Warning when install Python packages

Tags: python, pip

#### The problem:

**I have problem when I put this  command on Linux Terminal to install the Python packages**

```
pip install google-auth google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2 google-api-python-client
```

> WARNING: The scripts pyrsa-decrypt, pyrsa-encrypt, pyrsa-keygen, pyrsa-priv2pub, pyrsa-sign and pyrsa-verify are installed in '/home/kakashi/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
> WARNING: The script google-oauthlib-tool is installed in '/home/kakashi/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

**I try more and more but the Compilers like: VSCode, or PyCharm, my project not work because these 2-Warnings.**

Comment: Your warning message seems to indicate that you don't use a virtual env, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add '/home/kakashi/.local/bin' to the path

on windows - [Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

on linux - [How to Add a Directory to PATH in Linux](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-directory-to-path-in-linux/)